# How do I do a SQL Server XML XQuery that Keeps Returning Nulls

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have the following XML and the code to pull out this PYInvestmentIncomeAmt column but it keeps returning null. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the query at the bottom but it has to be just a small thing. I am going to be pulling out several other columns but I just need to get this one to work and then I can make my other columns work as well.

```
DECLARE @Doc XML
DECLARE @t TABLE (XMLid INT,
                  [Myxml] XML)

SET @Doc = 
('<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile" returnVersion="2018v3.1">
  <ReturnHeader binaryAttachmentCnt="0">
    <ReturnTs>2020-01-06T12:55:15-06:00</ReturnTs>
    <TaxPeriodEndDt>2019-06-30</TaxPeriodEndDt>
    </PreparerFirmGrp>
    <ReturnTypeCd>990</ReturnTypeCd>
    <TaxPeriodBeginDt>2018-07-01</TaxPeriodBeginDt>
    </ReturnHeader>
  <ReturnData documentCnt="6">
    <IRS990 documentId="RetDoc1038000001" referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1044400001">
      <PrincipalOfficerNm>JEFF STAUTER</PrincipalOfficerNm>
      <USAddress>
        <AddressLine1Txt>521 SOUTH WEST STREET</AddressLine1Txt>
        <CityNm>GALENA</CityNm>
        <StateAbbreviationCd>IL</StateAbbreviationCd>
        <ZIPCd>61036</ZIPCd>
      </USAddress>
      <PYInvestmentIncomeAmt>332</PYInvestmentIncomeAmt>
      <MissionDesc>TO PROVIDE SERVICES TO PEOPLE WITH LIFE LONG OR PERMANENT PHYSICAL, HEALTH AND DEVELOPMENTAL IMPAIRMENTS.</MissionDesc>
      <SignificantNewProgramSrvcInd>0</SignificantNewProgramSrvcInd>
      <SignificantChangeInd>0</SignificantChangeInd>
      <ExpenseAmt>114805</ExpenseAmt>
      <RevenueAmt>111810</RevenueAmt>
      <Desc>PROVIDING LOW INCOME HOUSING TO ADULTS WITH DEVELOPMENTAL DISABILITIES.</Desc>
      <TotalProgramServiceExpensesAmt>114805</TotalProgramServiceExpensesAmt>
      <DescribedInSection501c3Ind referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1039100001">1</DescribedInSection501c3Ind>
      <ScheduleBRequiredInd>0</ScheduleBRequiredInd>
      <PoliticalCampaignActyInd>0</PoliticalCampaignActyInd>
      <LobbyingActivitiesInd>0</LobbyingActivitiesInd>
      <SubjectToProxyTaxInd>0</SubjectToProxyTaxInd>
      <DonorAdvisedFundInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</DonorAdvisedFundInd>
      <ConservationEasementsInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ConservationEasementsInd>
      <CollectionsOfArtInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</CollectionsOfArtInd>
      <CreditCounselingInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</CreditCounselingInd>
      <TempOrPermanentEndowmentsInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</TempOrPermanentEndowmentsInd>
      <ReportLandBuildingEquipmentInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</ReportLandBuildingEquipmentInd>
      <ReportInvestmentsOtherSecInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ReportInvestmentsOtherSecInd>
      <ReportProgramRelatedInvstInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ReportProgramRelatedInvstInd>
      <ReportOtherAssetsInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ReportOtherAssetsInd>
      <ReportOtherLiabilitiesInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</ReportOtherLiabilitiesInd>
      <IncludeFIN48FootnoteInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</IncludeFIN48FootnoteInd>
      <IndependentAuditFinclStmtInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</IndependentAuditFinclStmtInd>
      <ConsolidatedAuditFinclStmtInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ConsolidatedAuditFinclStmtInd>
      <BooksInCareOfDetail>
        <BusinessName>
          <BusinessNameLine1Txt>JEFF STAUTERVICE PRESIDENT</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
        </BusinessName>
        <PhoneNum>8152886691</PhoneNum>
        <USAddress>
          <AddressLine1Txt>500 ANCHOR ROAD</AddressLine1Txt>
          <CityNm>DIXON</CityNm>
          <StateAbbreviationCd>IL</StateAbbreviationCd>
          <ZIPCd>61021</ZIPCd>
        </USAddress>
      </BooksInCareOfDetail>
      <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
        <PersonNm>RICHARD PILLER</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>PRESIDENT</TitleTxt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>2.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
        <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
        <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
        <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
        <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationAmt>0</OtherCompensationAmt>
      </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
      <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
        <PersonNm>JEFF STAUTER</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>VICE PRESIDENT</TitleTxt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>45.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
        <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
        <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
        <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
        <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>147797</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationAmt>16922</OtherCompensationAmt>
      </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
      <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
        <PersonNm>BRENDA NAILOR</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>SECRETARY/TREASURER</TitleTxt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>45.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
        <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
        <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
        <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
        <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>64242</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationAmt>15108</OtherCompensationAmt>
      </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
      <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
        <PersonNm>RON HEIDERSCHEIT</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>DIRECTOR</TitleTxt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
        <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
        <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
        <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationAmt>0</OtherCompensationAmt>
      </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
      <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
        <PersonNm>ARLAN MCCLAIN</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>DIRECTOR</TitleTxt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
        <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
        <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
        <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationAmt>0</OtherCompensationAmt>
      </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
      <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
        <PersonNm>NANCY SPARKS</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>CFO</TitleTxt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
        <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>45.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
        <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
        <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
        <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>68172</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationAmt>1363</OtherCompensationAmt>
      </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
      <TotalReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</TotalReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
      <TotReportableCompRltdOrgAmt>280211</TotReportableCompRltdOrgAmt>
      <TotalOtherCompensationAmt>33393</TotalOtherCompensationAmt>
      <IndivRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>0</IndivRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>
      <FormerOfcrEmployeesListedInd>0</FormerOfcrEmployeesListedInd>
      <TotalCompGreaterThan150KInd>1</TotalCompGreaterThan150KInd>
      <CompensationFromOtherSrcsInd>0</CompensationFromOtherSrcsInd>
      <CntrctRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>0</CntrctRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>
      <ProgramServiceRevenueGrp>
        <Desc>RENT INCOME</Desc>
        <BusinessCd>531110</BusinessCd>
        <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>111810</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
        <RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>111810</RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>
      </ProgramServiceRevenueGrp>
      <TotalProgramServiceRevenueAmt>111810</TotalProgramServiceRevenueAmt>
      <InvestmentIncomeGrp>
        <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>2400</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
        <ExclusionAmt>2400</ExclusionAmt>
      </InvestmentIncomeGrp>
      <GrossAmountSalesAssetsGrp>
        <SecuritiesAmt>100</SecuritiesAmt>
      </GrossAmountSalesAssetsGrp>
      <LessCostOthBasisSalesExpnssGrp>
        <SecuritiesAmt>443</SecuritiesAmt>
      </LessCostOthBasisSalesExpnssGrp>
      <GainOrLossGrp>
        <SecuritiesAmt>-343</SecuritiesAmt>
      </GainOrLossGrp>
      <NetGainOrLossInvestmentsGrp>
        <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>-343</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
        <ExclusionAmt>-343</ExclusionAmt>
      </NetGainOrLossInvestmentsGrp>
      <OtherRevenueMiscGrp>
        <Desc>LAUNDRY REVENUE</Desc>
        <BusinessCd>531110</BusinessCd>
        <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>1603</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
        <ExclusionAmt>1603</ExclusionAmt>
      </OtherRevenueMiscGrp>
      <OtherRevenueTotalAmt>1603</OtherRevenueTotalAmt>
      <TotalRevenueGrp>
        <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>115470</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
        <RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>111810</RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>
        <UnrelatedBusinessRevenueAmt>0</UnrelatedBusinessRevenueAmt>
        <ExclusionAmt>3660</ExclusionAmt>
      </TotalRevenueGrp>
      <FeesForServicesManagementGrp>
        <TotalAmt>19848</TotalAmt>
        <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>19848</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
      </FeesForServicesManagementGrp>
      <FeesForServicesAccountingGrp>
        <TotalAmt>11080</TotalAmt>
        <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>11080</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
      </FeesForServicesAccountingGrp>
      <OfficeExpensesGrp>
        <TotalAmt>2757</TotalAmt>
        <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>2757</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
      </OfficeExpensesGrp>
      <OccupancyGrp>
        <TotalAmt>36308</TotalAmt>
        <ProgramServicesAmt>36308</ProgramServicesAmt>
      </OccupancyGrp>
      <DepreciationDepletionGrp>
        <TotalAmt>43102</TotalAmt>
        <ProgramServicesAmt>43102</ProgramServicesAmt>
      </DepreciationDepletionGrp>
      <InsuranceGrp>
        <TotalAmt>3861</TotalAmt>
        <ProgramServicesAmt>3861</ProgramServicesAmt>
      </InsuranceGrp>
      <OtherExpensesGrp>
        <Desc>REPAIRS</Desc>
        <TotalAmt>23492</TotalAmt>
        <ProgramServicesAmt>23492</ProgramServicesAmt>
      </OtherExpensesGrp>
      <OtherExpensesGrp>
        <Desc>HUD REIMBURSEMENT</Desc>
        <TotalAmt>8042</TotalAmt>
        <ProgramServicesAmt>8042</ProgramServicesAmt>
      </OtherExpensesGrp>
      <TotalFunctionalExpensesGrp>
        <TotalAmt>148490</TotalAmt>
        <ProgramServicesAmt>114805</ProgramServicesAmt>
        <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>33685</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
        <FundraisingAmt>0</FundraisingAmt>
      </TotalFunctionalExpensesGrp>
      <CashNonInterestBearingGrp>
        <BOYAmt>1069</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>15542</EOYAmt>
      </CashNonInterestBearingGrp>
      <SavingsAndTempCashInvstGrp>
        <BOYAmt>177150</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>152313</EOYAmt>
      </SavingsAndTempCashInvstGrp>
      <AccountsReceivableGrp>
        <BOYAmt>0</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>3696</EOYAmt>
      </AccountsReceivableGrp>
      <LandBldgEquipCostOrOtherBssAmt>1189542</LandBldgEquipCostOrOtherBssAmt>
      <LandBldgEquipAccumDeprecAmt>820212</LandBldgEquipAccumDeprecAmt>
      <LandBldgEquipBasisNetGrp>
        <BOYAmt>395709</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>369330</EOYAmt>
      </LandBldgEquipBasisNetGrp>
      <InvestmentsPubTradedSecGrp>
        <BOYAmt>195486</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>201872</EOYAmt>
      </InvestmentsPubTradedSecGrp>
      <OtherAssetsTotalGrp>
        <BOYAmt>4669</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>4626</EOYAmt>
      </OtherAssetsTotalGrp>
      <TotalAssetsGrp>
        <BOYAmt>774083</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>747379</EOYAmt>
      </TotalAssetsGrp>
      <AccountsPayableAccrExpnssGrp>
        <BOYAmt>2088</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>3423</EOYAmt>
      </AccountsPayableAccrExpnssGrp>
      <MortgNotesPyblScrdInvstPropGrp>
        <BOYAmt>972322</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>972322</EOYAmt>
      </MortgNotesPyblScrdInvstPropGrp>
      <OtherLiabilitiesGrp>
        <BOYAmt>4669</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>4626</EOYAmt>
      </OtherLiabilitiesGrp>
      <TotalLiabilitiesGrp>
        <BOYAmt>979079</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>980371</EOYAmt>
      </TotalLiabilitiesGrp>
      <OrganizationFollowsSFAS117Ind>X</OrganizationFollowsSFAS117Ind>
      <UnrestrictedNetAssetsGrp>
        <BOYAmt>-204996</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>-232992</EOYAmt>
      </UnrestrictedNetAssetsGrp>
      <TotalNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
        <BOYAmt>-204996</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>-232992</EOYAmt>
      </TotalNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
      <TotLiabNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
        <BOYAmt>774083</BOYAmt>
        <EOYAmt>747379</EOYAmt>
      </TotLiabNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
      <ReconcilationRevenueExpnssAmt>-33020</ReconcilationRevenueExpnssAmt>
      <NetUnrlzdGainsLossesInvstAmt>5024</NetUnrlzdGainsLossesInvstAmt>
      <OtherChangesInNetAssetsAmt>0</OtherChangesInNetAssetsAmt>
      <MethodOfAccountingAccrualInd>X</MethodOfAccountingAccrualInd>
      <AccountantCompileOrReviewInd>0</AccountantCompileOrReviewInd>
      <FSAuditedInd>1</FSAuditedInd>
      <AuditCommitteeInd>1</AuditCommitteeInd>
      <FederalGrantAuditRequiredInd>1</FederalGrantAuditRequiredInd>
      <FederalGrantAuditPerformedInd>1</FederalGrantAuditPerformedInd>
    </IRS990>
    <IRS990ScheduleA documentId="RetDoc1039100001">
      <PubliclySupportedOrg509a2Ind>X</PubliclySupportedOrg509a2Ind>
      <GiftsGrantsContrisRcvd509Grp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>85</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <TotalAmt>85</TotalAmt>
      </GiftsGrantsContrisRcvd509Grp>
      <GrossReceiptsAdmissionsGrp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>97811</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>105561</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>108176</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>109451</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearAmt>111810</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
        <TotalAmt>532809</TotalAmt>
      </GrossReceiptsAdmissionsGrp>
      <Total509Grp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>97811</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>105646</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>108176</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>109451</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearAmt>111810</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
        <TotalAmt>532894</TotalAmt>
      </Total509Grp>
      <AmountsRcvdDsqlfyPersonGrp>
        <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
      </AmountsRcvdDsqlfyPersonGrp>
      <SubstantialContributorsAmtGrp>
        <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
      </SubstantialContributorsAmtGrp>
      <SubstAndDsqlfyPrsnsTotGrp>
        <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
      </SubstAndDsqlfyPrsnsTotGrp>
      <PublicSupportTotal509Amt>532894</PublicSupportTotal509Amt>
      <GrossInvestmentIncome509Grp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>1232</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>4481</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>1947</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>659</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearAmt>2400</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
        <TotalAmt>10719</TotalAmt>
      </GrossInvestmentIncome509Grp>
      <InvestmentIncomeAndUBTIGrp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>1232</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>4481</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>1947</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>659</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearAmt>2400</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
        <TotalAmt>10719</TotalAmt>
      </InvestmentIncomeAndUBTIGrp>
      <OtherIncome509Grp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>506</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>622</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>972</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>1433</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearAmt>1603</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
        <TotalAmt>5136</TotalAmt>
      </OtherIncome509Grp>
      <TotalSupportCalendarYearGrp>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>99549</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>110749</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>111095</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>111543</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
        <CurrentTaxYearAmt>115813</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
        <TotalAmt>548749</TotalAmt>
      </TotalSupportCalendarYearGrp>
      <PublicSupportCY509Pct>0.97110</PublicSupportCY509Pct>
      <PublicSupportPY509Pct>0.97150</PublicSupportPY509Pct>
      <InvestmentIncomeCYPct>0.01950</InvestmentIncomeCYPct>
      <InvestmentIncomePYPct>0.02130</InvestmentIncomePYPct>
      <ThirtyThrPctSuprtTestsCY509Ind>X</ThirtyThrPctSuprtTestsCY509Ind>
      <Form990ScheduleAPartVIGrp>
        <FormAndLineReferenceDesc>SCHEDULE A, PART III, LINE 12, EXPLANATION OF OTHER INCOME:</FormAndLineReferenceDesc>
        <ExplanationTxt>LAUNDRY REVENUE - 2014 AMOUNT: $ 506. 2015 AMOUNT: $ 622. 2016 AMOUNT: $ 972. 2017 AMOUNT: $ 1,433. 2018 AMOUNT: $ 1,603.</ExplanationTxt>
      </Form990ScheduleAPartVIGrp>
    </IRS990ScheduleA>
    <IRS990ScheduleD documentId="RetDoc1040000001">
      <LandGrp>
        <OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>28058</OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>
        <BookValueAmt>28058</BookValueAmt>
      </LandGrp>
      <BuildingsGrp>
        <OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>1061333</OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>
        <DepreciationAmt>727584</DepreciationAmt>
        <BookValueAmt>333749</BookValueAmt>
      </BuildingsGrp>
      <OtherLandBuildingsGrp>
        <OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>100151</OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>
        <DepreciationAmt>92628</DepreciationAmt>
        <BookValueAmt>7523</BookValueAmt>
      </OtherLandBuildingsGrp>
      <TotalBookValueLandBuildingsAmt>369330</TotalBookValueLandBuildingsAmt>
      <OtherLiabilitiesOrgGrp>
        <Desc>TENANT DEPOSITS</Desc>
        <Amt>4626</Amt>
      </OtherLiabilitiesOrgGrp>
      <TotalLiabilityAmt>4626</TotalLiabilityAmt>
      <FootnoteTextInd>X</FootnoteTextInd>
      <TotalRevEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>120494</TotalRevEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>
      <NetUnrealizedGainsInvstAmt>5024</NetUnrealizedGainsInvstAmt>
      <RevenueNotReportedAmt>5024</RevenueNotReportedAmt>
      <RevenueSubtotalAmt>115470</RevenueSubtotalAmt>
      <RevenueNotReportedFinclStmtAmt>0</RevenueNotReportedFinclStmtAmt>
      <TotalRevenuePerForm990Amt>115470</TotalRevenuePerForm990Amt>
      <TotExpnsEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>148490</TotExpnsEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>
      <ExpensesNotReportedAmt>0</ExpensesNotReportedAmt>
      <ExpensesSubtotalAmt>148490</ExpensesSubtotalAmt>
      <ExpensesNotRptFinclStmtAmt>0</ExpensesNotRptFinclStmtAmt>
      <TotalExpensesPerForm990Amt>148490</TotalExpensesPerForm990Amt>
      <SupplementalInformationDetail>
        <FormAndLineReferenceDesc>PART X, LINE 2:</FormAndLineReferenceDesc>
        <ExplanationTxt>THE ORGANIZATION IS A NOT-FOR-PROFIT CORPORATION AS DESCRIBED IN SECTION 501(C)(3) OF INTERNAL REVENUE CODE AND AS SUCH IS EXEMPT FROM FEDERAL INCOME TAXES. THE ORGANIZATION IS CLASSIFIED BY THE INTERNAL REVENUE SERVICE AS OTHER THAN A PRIVATE FOUNDATION. THE ORGANIZATION ACCOUNTS FOR UNCERTAINTY IN INCOME TAXES UNDER THE AUTHORITATIVE GUIDANCE ISSUED BY FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING STANDARDS BOARD ("FASB"). THE ORGANIZATION USES A THRESHOLD OF MORE-LIKELY-THAN-NOT TO BE SUSTAINED UPON EXAMINATION TO ACCOUNT FOR UNCERTAINTY INCOME TAXES. MEASUREMENT OF THE TAX UNCERTAINTY OCCURS IF THE RECOGNITION THRESHOLD HAS NOT BEEN MET. THIS GUIDANCE ALSO ADDRESSES DERECOGNITION, CLASSIFICATION, INTEREST AND PENALTIES, DISCLOSURE, AND TRANSITION. THE ORGANIZATION CONDUCTS BUSINESS SOLELY IN THE U.S. AND, AS A RESULT, FILES FEDERAL AND ILLINOIS TAX RETURNS. IN THE NORMAL COURSE OF BUSINESS THE ORGANIZATION IS SUBJECT TO EXAMINATION BY TAXING AUTHORITIES. PRESENTLY, THERE ARE NO ONGOING INCOME TAX AUDITS OR UNRESOLVED DISPUTES WITH THE TAX AUTHORITIES THAT THE ORGANIZATION CURRENTLY FILES OR HAS FILED WITH.</ExplanationTxt>
      </SupplementalInformationDetail>
    </IRS990ScheduleD>
    <IRS990ScheduleJ documentId="RetDoc1042400001">
      <SeverancePaymentInd>0</SeverancePaymentInd>
      <SupplementalNonqualRtrPlanInd>0</SupplementalNonqualRtrPlanInd>
      <EquityBasedCompArrngmInd>0</EquityBasedCompArrngmInd>
      <CompBasedOnRevenueOfFlngOrgInd>0</CompBasedOnRevenueOfFlngOrgInd>
      <CompBsdOnRevRelatedOrgsInd>0</CompBsdOnRevRelatedOrgsInd>
      <CompBsdNetEarnsFlngOrgInd>0</CompBsdNetEarnsFlngOrgInd>
      <CompBsdNetEarnsRltdOrgsInd>0</CompBsdNetEarnsRltdOrgsInd>
      <AnyNonFixedPaymentsInd>0</AnyNonFixedPaymentsInd>
      <InitialContractExceptionInd>0</InitialContractExceptionInd>
      <RltdOrgOfficerTrstKeyEmplGrp>
        <PersonNm>JEFF STAUTER</PersonNm>
        <TitleTxt>VICE PRESIDENT</TitleTxt>
        <BaseCompensationFilingOrgAmt>0</BaseCompensationFilingOrgAmt>
        <CompensationBasedOnRltdOrgsAmt>147797</CompensationBasedOnRltdOrgsAmt>
        <BonusFilingOrganizationAmount>0</BonusFilingOrganizationAmount>
        <BonusRelatedOrganizationsAmt>0</BonusRelatedOrganizationsAmt>
        <OtherCompensationFilingOrgAmt>0</OtherCompensationFilingOrgAmt>
        <OtherCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>0</OtherCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>
        <DeferredCompensationFlngOrgAmt>0</DeferredCompensationFlngOrgAmt>
        <DeferredCompRltdOrgsAmt>0</DeferredCompRltdOrgsAmt>
        <NontaxableBenefitsFilingOrgAmt>0</NontaxableBenefitsFilingOrgAmt>
        <NontaxableBenefitsRltdOrgsAmt>16922</NontaxableBenefitsRltdOrgsAmt>
        <TotalCompensationFilingOrgAmt>0</TotalCompensationFilingOrgAmt>
        <TotalCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>164719</TotalCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>
        <CompReportPrior990FilingOrgAmt>0</CompReportPrior990FilingOrgAmt>
        <CompReportPrior990RltdOrgsAmt>0</CompReportPrior990RltdOrgsAmt>
      </RltdOrgOfficerTrstKeyEmplGrp>
      <SupplementalInformationDetail>
        <FormAndLineReferenceDesc>PART I, LINE 3</FormAndLineReferenceDesc>
        <ExplanationTxt>COMPENSATION IS REVIEWED AND SET BY A COMPENSATION COMMITTEE WHICH IS A GROUP OF BOARD MEMBERS. THIS COMMITTEE REVIEWS SALARY SURVEYS AND 990''S OF LIKE AGENCIES WITH SIMILAR BUDGET SIZE TO DETERMINE COMPENSATION AND ESTABLISH THE EMPLOYMENT CONTRACT WHICH IS THEN APPROVED BY THE BOARD OF DIRECTORS. THIS PROCESS IS DONE CURRENTLY AT 3 YEAR INTERVALS.</ExplanationTxt>
      </SupplementalInformationDetail>
    </IRS990ScheduleJ>
  </ReturnData>
</Return>')

INSERT @t VALUES(1,@Doc)

SELECT XMLid, z.value('PYInvestmentIncomeAmt[1]','CHAR(12)')
                AS PYInvestmentIncomeAmt
FROM @t AS t
OUTER APPLY t.Myxml.nodes('/Return/ReturnData/IRS990') as r(z)
```

Comment: I get [an XML parsing error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3eed4c667d5d02f5857f3d91adbdcf5c) when running your query, but the issue is probably that you need to use [`WITH XMLNAMPESPACES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-ver16) to define your namespaces.

Comment: The XML is not well-formed. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

A default namespace was taken into account.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Return xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.irs.gov/efile" returnVersion="2018v3.1">
    <ReturnHeader binaryAttachmentCnt="0">
        <ReturnTs>2020-01-06T12:55:15-06:00</ReturnTs>
        <TaxPeriodEndDt>2019-06-30</TaxPeriodEndDt>
        <!--</PreparerFirmGrp>-->
        <ReturnTypeCd>990</ReturnTypeCd>
        <TaxPeriodBeginDt>2018-07-01</TaxPeriodBeginDt>
    </ReturnHeader>
    <ReturnData documentCnt="6">
        <IRS990 documentId="RetDoc1038000001" referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1044400001">
            <PrincipalOfficerNm>JEFF STAUTER</PrincipalOfficerNm>
            <USAddress>
                <AddressLine1Txt>521 SOUTH WEST STREET</AddressLine1Txt>
                <CityNm>GALENA</CityNm>
                <StateAbbreviationCd>IL</StateAbbreviationCd>
                <ZIPCd>61036</ZIPCd>
            </USAddress>
            <PYInvestmentIncomeAmt>332</PYInvestmentIncomeAmt>
            <MissionDesc>TO PROVIDE SERVICES TO PEOPLE WITH LIFE LONG OR PERMANENT PHYSICAL, HEALTH AND DEVELOPMENTAL IMPAIRMENTS.</MissionDesc>
            <SignificantNewProgramSrvcInd>0</SignificantNewProgramSrvcInd>
            <SignificantChangeInd>0</SignificantChangeInd>
            <ExpenseAmt>114805</ExpenseAmt>
            <RevenueAmt>111810</RevenueAmt>
            <Desc>PROVIDING LOW INCOME HOUSING TO ADULTS WITH DEVELOPMENTAL DISABILITIES.</Desc>
            <TotalProgramServiceExpensesAmt>114805</TotalProgramServiceExpensesAmt>
            <DescribedInSection501c3Ind referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1039100001">1</DescribedInSection501c3Ind>
            <ScheduleBRequiredInd>0</ScheduleBRequiredInd>
            <PoliticalCampaignActyInd>0</PoliticalCampaignActyInd>
            <LobbyingActivitiesInd>0</LobbyingActivitiesInd>
            <SubjectToProxyTaxInd>0</SubjectToProxyTaxInd>
            <DonorAdvisedFundInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</DonorAdvisedFundInd>
            <ConservationEasementsInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ConservationEasementsInd>
            <CollectionsOfArtInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</CollectionsOfArtInd>
            <CreditCounselingInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</CreditCounselingInd>
            <TempOrPermanentEndowmentsInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</TempOrPermanentEndowmentsInd>
            <ReportLandBuildingEquipmentInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</ReportLandBuildingEquipmentInd>
            <ReportInvestmentsOtherSecInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ReportInvestmentsOtherSecInd>
            <ReportProgramRelatedInvstInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ReportProgramRelatedInvstInd>
            <ReportOtherAssetsInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ReportOtherAssetsInd>
            <ReportOtherLiabilitiesInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</ReportOtherLiabilitiesInd>
            <IncludeFIN48FootnoteInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</IncludeFIN48FootnoteInd>
            <IndependentAuditFinclStmtInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">1</IndependentAuditFinclStmtInd>
            <ConsolidatedAuditFinclStmtInd referenceDocumentId="RetDoc1040000001">0</ConsolidatedAuditFinclStmtInd>
            <BooksInCareOfDetail>
                <BusinessName>
                    <BusinessNameLine1Txt>JEFF STAUTERVICE PRESIDENT</BusinessNameLine1Txt>
                </BusinessName>
                <PhoneNum>8152886691</PhoneNum>
                <USAddress>
                    <AddressLine1Txt>500 ANCHOR ROAD</AddressLine1Txt>
                    <CityNm>DIXON</CityNm>
                    <StateAbbreviationCd>IL</StateAbbreviationCd>
                    <ZIPCd>61021</ZIPCd>
                </USAddress>
            </BooksInCareOfDetail>
            <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
                <PersonNm>RICHARD PILLER</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>PRESIDENT</TitleTxt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>2.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
                <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
                <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
                <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
                <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationAmt>0</OtherCompensationAmt>
            </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
            <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
                <PersonNm>JEFF STAUTER</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>VICE PRESIDENT</TitleTxt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>45.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
                <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
                <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
                <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
                <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>147797</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationAmt>16922</OtherCompensationAmt>
            </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
            <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
                <PersonNm>BRENDA NAILOR</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>SECRETARY/TREASURER</TitleTxt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>45.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
                <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
                <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
                <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
                <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>64242</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationAmt>15108</OtherCompensationAmt>
            </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
            <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
                <PersonNm>RON HEIDERSCHEIT</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>DIRECTOR</TitleTxt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
                <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
                <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
                <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationAmt>0</OtherCompensationAmt>
            </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
            <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
                <PersonNm>ARLAN MCCLAIN</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>DIRECTOR</TitleTxt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
                <IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>X</IndividualTrusteeOrDirectorInd>
                <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
                <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationAmt>0</OtherCompensationAmt>
            </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
            <Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
                <PersonNm>NANCY SPARKS</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>CFO</TitleTxt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRt>1.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRt>
                <AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>45.00</AverageHoursPerWeekRltdOrgRt>
                <OfficerInd>X</OfficerInd>
                <ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</ReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
                <ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>68172</ReportableCompFromRltdOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationAmt>1363</OtherCompensationAmt>
            </Form990PartVIISectionAGrp>
            <TotalReportableCompFromOrgAmt>0</TotalReportableCompFromOrgAmt>
            <TotReportableCompRltdOrgAmt>280211</TotReportableCompRltdOrgAmt>
            <TotalOtherCompensationAmt>33393</TotalOtherCompensationAmt>
            <IndivRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>0</IndivRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>
            <FormerOfcrEmployeesListedInd>0</FormerOfcrEmployeesListedInd>
            <TotalCompGreaterThan150KInd>1</TotalCompGreaterThan150KInd>
            <CompensationFromOtherSrcsInd>0</CompensationFromOtherSrcsInd>
            <CntrctRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>0</CntrctRcvdGreaterThan100KCnt>
            <ProgramServiceRevenueGrp>
                <Desc>RENT INCOME</Desc>
                <BusinessCd>531110</BusinessCd>
                <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>111810</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
                <RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>111810</RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>
            </ProgramServiceRevenueGrp>
            <TotalProgramServiceRevenueAmt>111810</TotalProgramServiceRevenueAmt>
            <InvestmentIncomeGrp>
                <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>2400</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
                <ExclusionAmt>2400</ExclusionAmt>
            </InvestmentIncomeGrp>
            <GrossAmountSalesAssetsGrp>
                <SecuritiesAmt>100</SecuritiesAmt>
            </GrossAmountSalesAssetsGrp>
            <LessCostOthBasisSalesExpnssGrp>
                <SecuritiesAmt>443</SecuritiesAmt>
            </LessCostOthBasisSalesExpnssGrp>
            <GainOrLossGrp>
                <SecuritiesAmt>-343</SecuritiesAmt>
            </GainOrLossGrp>
            <NetGainOrLossInvestmentsGrp>
                <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>-343</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
                <ExclusionAmt>-343</ExclusionAmt>
            </NetGainOrLossInvestmentsGrp>
            <OtherRevenueMiscGrp>
                <Desc>LAUNDRY REVENUE</Desc>
                <BusinessCd>531110</BusinessCd>
                <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>1603</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
                <ExclusionAmt>1603</ExclusionAmt>
            </OtherRevenueMiscGrp>
            <OtherRevenueTotalAmt>1603</OtherRevenueTotalAmt>
            <TotalRevenueGrp>
                <TotalRevenueColumnAmt>115470</TotalRevenueColumnAmt>
                <RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>111810</RelatedOrExemptFuncIncomeAmt>
                <UnrelatedBusinessRevenueAmt>0</UnrelatedBusinessRevenueAmt>
                <ExclusionAmt>3660</ExclusionAmt>
            </TotalRevenueGrp>
            <FeesForServicesManagementGrp>
                <TotalAmt>19848</TotalAmt>
                <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>19848</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
            </FeesForServicesManagementGrp>
            <FeesForServicesAccountingGrp>
                <TotalAmt>11080</TotalAmt>
                <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>11080</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
            </FeesForServicesAccountingGrp>
            <OfficeExpensesGrp>
                <TotalAmt>2757</TotalAmt>
                <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>2757</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
            </OfficeExpensesGrp>
            <OccupancyGrp>
                <TotalAmt>36308</TotalAmt>
                <ProgramServicesAmt>36308</ProgramServicesAmt>
            </OccupancyGrp>
            <DepreciationDepletionGrp>
                <TotalAmt>43102</TotalAmt>
                <ProgramServicesAmt>43102</ProgramServicesAmt>
            </DepreciationDepletionGrp>
            <InsuranceGrp>
                <TotalAmt>3861</TotalAmt>
                <ProgramServicesAmt>3861</ProgramServicesAmt>
            </InsuranceGrp>
            <OtherExpensesGrp>
                <Desc>REPAIRS</Desc>
                <TotalAmt>23492</TotalAmt>
                <ProgramServicesAmt>23492</ProgramServicesAmt>
            </OtherExpensesGrp>
            <OtherExpensesGrp>
                <Desc>HUD REIMBURSEMENT</Desc>
                <TotalAmt>8042</TotalAmt>
                <ProgramServicesAmt>8042</ProgramServicesAmt>
            </OtherExpensesGrp>
            <TotalFunctionalExpensesGrp>
                <TotalAmt>148490</TotalAmt>
                <ProgramServicesAmt>114805</ProgramServicesAmt>
                <ManagementAndGeneralAmt>33685</ManagementAndGeneralAmt>
                <FundraisingAmt>0</FundraisingAmt>
            </TotalFunctionalExpensesGrp>
            <CashNonInterestBearingGrp>
                <BOYAmt>1069</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>15542</EOYAmt>
            </CashNonInterestBearingGrp>
            <SavingsAndTempCashInvstGrp>
                <BOYAmt>177150</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>152313</EOYAmt>
            </SavingsAndTempCashInvstGrp>
            <AccountsReceivableGrp>
                <BOYAmt>0</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>3696</EOYAmt>
            </AccountsReceivableGrp>
            <LandBldgEquipCostOrOtherBssAmt>1189542</LandBldgEquipCostOrOtherBssAmt>
            <LandBldgEquipAccumDeprecAmt>820212</LandBldgEquipAccumDeprecAmt>
            <LandBldgEquipBasisNetGrp>
                <BOYAmt>395709</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>369330</EOYAmt>
            </LandBldgEquipBasisNetGrp>
            <InvestmentsPubTradedSecGrp>
                <BOYAmt>195486</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>201872</EOYAmt>
            </InvestmentsPubTradedSecGrp>
            <OtherAssetsTotalGrp>
                <BOYAmt>4669</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>4626</EOYAmt>
            </OtherAssetsTotalGrp>
            <TotalAssetsGrp>
                <BOYAmt>774083</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>747379</EOYAmt>
            </TotalAssetsGrp>
            <AccountsPayableAccrExpnssGrp>
                <BOYAmt>2088</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>3423</EOYAmt>
            </AccountsPayableAccrExpnssGrp>
            <MortgNotesPyblScrdInvstPropGrp>
                <BOYAmt>972322</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>972322</EOYAmt>
            </MortgNotesPyblScrdInvstPropGrp>
            <OtherLiabilitiesGrp>
                <BOYAmt>4669</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>4626</EOYAmt>
            </OtherLiabilitiesGrp>
            <TotalLiabilitiesGrp>
                <BOYAmt>979079</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>980371</EOYAmt>
            </TotalLiabilitiesGrp>
            <OrganizationFollowsSFAS117Ind>X</OrganizationFollowsSFAS117Ind>
            <UnrestrictedNetAssetsGrp>
                <BOYAmt>-204996</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>-232992</EOYAmt>
            </UnrestrictedNetAssetsGrp>
            <TotalNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
                <BOYAmt>-204996</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>-232992</EOYAmt>
            </TotalNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
            <TotLiabNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
                <BOYAmt>774083</BOYAmt>
                <EOYAmt>747379</EOYAmt>
            </TotLiabNetAssetsFundBalanceGrp>
            <ReconcilationRevenueExpnssAmt>-33020</ReconcilationRevenueExpnssAmt>
            <NetUnrlzdGainsLossesInvstAmt>5024</NetUnrlzdGainsLossesInvstAmt>
            <OtherChangesInNetAssetsAmt>0</OtherChangesInNetAssetsAmt>
            <MethodOfAccountingAccrualInd>X</MethodOfAccountingAccrualInd>
            <AccountantCompileOrReviewInd>0</AccountantCompileOrReviewInd>
            <FSAuditedInd>1</FSAuditedInd>
            <AuditCommitteeInd>1</AuditCommitteeInd>
            <FederalGrantAuditRequiredInd>1</FederalGrantAuditRequiredInd>
            <FederalGrantAuditPerformedInd>1</FederalGrantAuditPerformedInd>
        </IRS990>
        <IRS990ScheduleA documentId="RetDoc1039100001">
            <PubliclySupportedOrg509a2Ind>X</PubliclySupportedOrg509a2Ind>
            <GiftsGrantsContrisRcvd509Grp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>85</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <TotalAmt>85</TotalAmt>
            </GiftsGrantsContrisRcvd509Grp>
            <GrossReceiptsAdmissionsGrp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>97811</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>105561</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>108176</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>109451</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearAmt>111810</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
                <TotalAmt>532809</TotalAmt>
            </GrossReceiptsAdmissionsGrp>
            <Total509Grp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>97811</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>105646</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>108176</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>109451</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearAmt>111810</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
                <TotalAmt>532894</TotalAmt>
            </Total509Grp>
            <AmountsRcvdDsqlfyPersonGrp>
                <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
            </AmountsRcvdDsqlfyPersonGrp>
            <SubstantialContributorsAmtGrp>
                <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
            </SubstantialContributorsAmtGrp>
            <SubstAndDsqlfyPrsnsTotGrp>
                <TotalAmt>0</TotalAmt>
            </SubstAndDsqlfyPrsnsTotGrp>
            <PublicSupportTotal509Amt>532894</PublicSupportTotal509Amt>
            <GrossInvestmentIncome509Grp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>1232</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>4481</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>1947</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>659</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearAmt>2400</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
                <TotalAmt>10719</TotalAmt>
            </GrossInvestmentIncome509Grp>
            <InvestmentIncomeAndUBTIGrp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>1232</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>4481</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>1947</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>659</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearAmt>2400</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
                <TotalAmt>10719</TotalAmt>
            </InvestmentIncomeAndUBTIGrp>
            <OtherIncome509Grp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>506</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>622</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>972</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>1433</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearAmt>1603</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
                <TotalAmt>5136</TotalAmt>
            </OtherIncome509Grp>
            <TotalSupportCalendarYearGrp>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>99549</CurrentTaxYearMinus4YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>110749</CurrentTaxYearMinus3YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>111095</CurrentTaxYearMinus2YearsAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>111543</CurrentTaxYearMinus1YearAmt>
                <CurrentTaxYearAmt>115813</CurrentTaxYearAmt>
                <TotalAmt>548749</TotalAmt>
            </TotalSupportCalendarYearGrp>
            <PublicSupportCY509Pct>0.97110</PublicSupportCY509Pct>
            <PublicSupportPY509Pct>0.97150</PublicSupportPY509Pct>
            <InvestmentIncomeCYPct>0.01950</InvestmentIncomeCYPct>
            <InvestmentIncomePYPct>0.02130</InvestmentIncomePYPct>
            <ThirtyThrPctSuprtTestsCY509Ind>X</ThirtyThrPctSuprtTestsCY509Ind>
            <Form990ScheduleAPartVIGrp>
                <FormAndLineReferenceDesc>SCHEDULE A, PART III, LINE 12, EXPLANATION OF OTHER INCOME:</FormAndLineReferenceDesc>
                <ExplanationTxt>LAUNDRY REVENUE - 2014 AMOUNT: $ 506. 2015 AMOUNT: $ 622. 2016 AMOUNT: $ 972. 2017 AMOUNT: $ 1,433. 2018 AMOUNT: $ 1,603.</ExplanationTxt>
            </Form990ScheduleAPartVIGrp>
        </IRS990ScheduleA>
        <IRS990ScheduleD documentId="RetDoc1040000001">
            <LandGrp>
                <OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>28058</OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>
                <BookValueAmt>28058</BookValueAmt>
            </LandGrp>
            <BuildingsGrp>
                <OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>1061333</OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>
                <DepreciationAmt>727584</DepreciationAmt>
                <BookValueAmt>333749</BookValueAmt>
            </BuildingsGrp>
            <OtherLandBuildingsGrp>
                <OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>100151</OtherCostOrOtherBasisAmt>
                <DepreciationAmt>92628</DepreciationAmt>
                <BookValueAmt>7523</BookValueAmt>
            </OtherLandBuildingsGrp>
            <TotalBookValueLandBuildingsAmt>369330</TotalBookValueLandBuildingsAmt>
            <OtherLiabilitiesOrgGrp>
                <Desc>TENANT DEPOSITS</Desc>
                <Amt>4626</Amt>
            </OtherLiabilitiesOrgGrp>
            <TotalLiabilityAmt>4626</TotalLiabilityAmt>
            <FootnoteTextInd>X</FootnoteTextInd>
            <TotalRevEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>120494</TotalRevEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>
            <NetUnrealizedGainsInvstAmt>5024</NetUnrealizedGainsInvstAmt>
            <RevenueNotReportedAmt>5024</RevenueNotReportedAmt>
            <RevenueSubtotalAmt>115470</RevenueSubtotalAmt>
            <RevenueNotReportedFinclStmtAmt>0</RevenueNotReportedFinclStmtAmt>
            <TotalRevenuePerForm990Amt>115470</TotalRevenuePerForm990Amt>
            <TotExpnsEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>148490</TotExpnsEtcAuditedFinclStmtAmt>
            <ExpensesNotReportedAmt>0</ExpensesNotReportedAmt>
            <ExpensesSubtotalAmt>148490</ExpensesSubtotalAmt>
            <ExpensesNotRptFinclStmtAmt>0</ExpensesNotRptFinclStmtAmt>
            <TotalExpensesPerForm990Amt>148490</TotalExpensesPerForm990Amt>
            <SupplementalInformationDetail>
                <FormAndLineReferenceDesc>PART X, LINE 2:</FormAndLineReferenceDesc>
                <ExplanationTxt>THE ORGANIZATION IS A NOT-FOR-PROFIT CORPORATION AS DESCRIBED IN SECTION 501(C)(3) OF INTERNAL REVENUE CODE AND AS SUCH IS EXEMPT FROM FEDERAL INCOME TAXES. THE ORGANIZATION IS CLASSIFIED BY THE INTERNAL REVENUE SERVICE AS OTHER THAN A PRIVATE FOUNDATION. THE ORGANIZATION ACCOUNTS FOR UNCERTAINTY IN INCOME TAXES UNDER THE AUTHORITATIVE GUIDANCE ISSUED BY FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING STANDARDS BOARD ("FASB"). THE ORGANIZATION USES A THRESHOLD OF MORE-LIKELY-THAN-NOT TO BE SUSTAINED UPON EXAMINATION TO ACCOUNT FOR UNCERTAINTY INCOME TAXES. MEASUREMENT OF THE TAX UNCERTAINTY OCCURS IF THE RECOGNITION THRESHOLD HAS NOT BEEN MET. THIS GUIDANCE ALSO ADDRESSES DERECOGNITION, CLASSIFICATION, INTEREST AND PENALTIES, DISCLOSURE, AND TRANSITION. THE ORGANIZATION CONDUCTS BUSINESS SOLELY IN THE U.S. AND, AS A RESULT, FILES FEDERAL AND ILLINOIS TAX RETURNS. IN THE NORMAL COURSE OF BUSINESS THE ORGANIZATION IS SUBJECT TO EXAMINATION BY TAXING AUTHORITIES. PRESENTLY, THERE ARE NO ONGOING INCOME TAX AUDITS OR UNRESOLVED DISPUTES WITH THE TAX AUTHORITIES THAT THE ORGANIZATION CURRENTLY FILES OR HAS FILED WITH.</ExplanationTxt>
            </SupplementalInformationDetail>
        </IRS990ScheduleD>
        <IRS990ScheduleJ documentId="RetDoc1042400001">
            <SeverancePaymentInd>0</SeverancePaymentInd>
            <SupplementalNonqualRtrPlanInd>0</SupplementalNonqualRtrPlanInd>
            <EquityBasedCompArrngmInd>0</EquityBasedCompArrngmInd>
            <CompBasedOnRevenueOfFlngOrgInd>0</CompBasedOnRevenueOfFlngOrgInd>
            <CompBsdOnRevRelatedOrgsInd>0</CompBsdOnRevRelatedOrgsInd>
            <CompBsdNetEarnsFlngOrgInd>0</CompBsdNetEarnsFlngOrgInd>
            <CompBsdNetEarnsRltdOrgsInd>0</CompBsdNetEarnsRltdOrgsInd>
            <AnyNonFixedPaymentsInd>0</AnyNonFixedPaymentsInd>
            <InitialContractExceptionInd>0</InitialContractExceptionInd>
            <RltdOrgOfficerTrstKeyEmplGrp>
                <PersonNm>JEFF STAUTER</PersonNm>
                <TitleTxt>VICE PRESIDENT</TitleTxt>
                <BaseCompensationFilingOrgAmt>0</BaseCompensationFilingOrgAmt>
                <CompensationBasedOnRltdOrgsAmt>147797</CompensationBasedOnRltdOrgsAmt>
                <BonusFilingOrganizationAmount>0</BonusFilingOrganizationAmount>
                <BonusRelatedOrganizationsAmt>0</BonusRelatedOrganizationsAmt>
                <OtherCompensationFilingOrgAmt>0</OtherCompensationFilingOrgAmt>
                <OtherCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>0</OtherCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>
                <DeferredCompensationFlngOrgAmt>0</DeferredCompensationFlngOrgAmt>
                <DeferredCompRltdOrgsAmt>0</DeferredCompRltdOrgsAmt>
                <NontaxableBenefitsFilingOrgAmt>0</NontaxableBenefitsFilingOrgAmt>
                <NontaxableBenefitsRltdOrgsAmt>16922</NontaxableBenefitsRltdOrgsAmt>
                <TotalCompensationFilingOrgAmt>0</TotalCompensationFilingOrgAmt>
                <TotalCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>164719</TotalCompensationRltdOrgsAmt>
                <CompReportPrior990FilingOrgAmt>0</CompReportPrior990FilingOrgAmt>
                <CompReportPrior990RltdOrgsAmt>0</CompReportPrior990RltdOrgsAmt>
            </RltdOrgOfficerTrstKeyEmplGrp>
            <SupplementalInformationDetail>
                <FormAndLineReferenceDesc>PART I, LINE 3</FormAndLineReferenceDesc>
                <ExplanationTxt>COMPENSATION IS REVIEWED AND SET BY A COMPENSATION COMMITTEE WHICH IS A GROUP OF BOARD MEMBERS. THIS COMMITTEE REVIEWS SALARY SURVEYS AND 990''S OF LIKE AGENCIES WITH SIMILAR BUDGET SIZE TO DETERMINE COMPENSATION AND ESTABLISH THE EMPLOYMENT CONTRACT WHICH IS THEN APPROVED BY THE BOARD OF DIRECTORS. THIS PROCESS IS DONE CURRENTLY AT 3 YEAR INTERVALS.</ExplanationTxt>
            </SupplementalInformationDetail>
        </IRS990ScheduleJ>
    </ReturnData>
</Return>');

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.irs.gov/efile')
SELECT ID
    , c.value('(PYInvestmentIncomeAmt/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(12)') AS PYInvestmentIncomeAmt
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Return/ReturnData/IRS990') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------+
| ID | PYInvestmentIncomeAmt |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 |                   332 |
+----+-----------------------+
```